# Vim sign: Linter indications with RltvNmbr script

Tags: vim, linter

I use the [RltvNmbr](https://github.com/vim-scripts/RltvNmbr.vim) script to achieve permanently visible hybrid numbers like so

```
set number
autocmd VimEnter * RltvNmbr
```

which is imo a better solution than [Jeff Kreeftmeijer's approach](https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/vim-number/).

The problem is, that RltvNmbr (extensively) uses the Vim's [sign](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/sign.html) feature and blocks and 'monopolizes' the sign pane, which is a problem when working with a linter (Ale) which indicates it's results via signs (and actually for anything that utilizes the signs feature!).

Linter indications are still displayed but only if the cursor is on the relevant line, otherwise nothing is displayed but the relative numbers.

Can anyone think of a solution for this, eg. how to use a third sign line for the relative numbers or the linter indication?

Comment: See also https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/50sy1l/the_battle_for_the_sign_column/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sign column, as well as the overall layout of fold / sign / number columns is hard-coded in Vim's core C implementation. You cannot easily change this.

I'm surprised that you prefer the *RltvNmbr* plugin over the `'relativenumber'` option, which now has been in Vim for quite some time. The plugin was implemented (in a hackish way) grabbing the sign column as a workaround for those people who desperately wanted relative numbers long before that feature made it into Vim. I consider that plugin as obsolete. (I only occasionally refer people to its implementation for ideas how to implement similar features within the sign column.)

For a robust solution, I'd highly recommend to switch to `'relativenumber'`; this will free up the sign columns for plugins like Ale.

Comment: thx for your answer! As I said, I use the RltvNmbr script to achieve permanently visible hybrid numbers (both numbers and relativenumbers), which isn't possible with the relativenumber.

Comment: Isn't it enough for you to have the current line show the absolute number, and only those around being relative (cp. `:help number_relativenumber`)? Having both columns at the same time seems like a waste of space for me. Also, plugins like my [RelativeNumberCurrentWindow plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4461) let you tweak what gets displayed (on window, or current mode) further.

Comment: I guess I'll have to switch to the relativenumber option, I liked the permanently visible hybrid numbers, but if you think about it, it really doesn't make much sense.. Thx!